# Modifing the "X" close button of highslide popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highslide

I'm using highslide in conjunction with highcharts and I want to modify the close button, more specifically, I want to call an additional function when a user clicks that "X" button.

When I inspect that "X" button, I get this in my console

```
<a href="#" title="Close (esc)" onclick="return hs.close(this)"><span>Close</span></a>
```

I want to do something like this

```
<a href="#" title="Close (esc)" onclick="return hs.close(this);myotherfunction();"><span>Close</span></a>
```

But I am unable to find where the code for that is located.

I have tried adding this to my header in the html file itself, in addition to the highslide.config.js to manually override but it has not worked.

```
hs.registerOverlay({
   html: '<div class="closebutton" onclick="return hs.close(this)" title="Close"></div>',
   position: 'top right',
   fade: 2 // fading the semi-transparent overlay looks bad in IE
});
```

Could somebody give me a helping hand?

////////////////////////////// updated
Thanks to Jeff B, I was able to accomplish the desired task using code that looks like this (although the example shown by Jeff B also works):

```
cursor: 'pointer',
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(event) {
            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                pageOrigin: {
                    x: this.pageX,
                    y: this.pageY
                },
                headingText: this.ticker,
                maincontentText: '<b>Detail:</b> ' + this.info,
                width: 250
            });

            alert('function goes here');

            hs.Expander.prototype.onBeforeClose = function(sender) {
                alert('function goes here');
            }               
        },
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why modify the button?  Highslide provides an `onBeforeClose` prototype:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onBeforeClose = function (sender) {
   myotherfunction();
}
```

There is also an `onAfterClose` prototype if you want different timing.

[onBeforeClose Documentation](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.onBeforeClose)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xjKFp/

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Instead of making it a separate function at the bottom, I included it inside events, and the click: function()   brackets. like in my updated post. Is there a difference between doing it this way, and doing it your way? any pros and cons?

Comment: @D3Chiq: The way you do it, you are applying the prototype function *every* time you open the chart.  You really only want to do it once.  Doing it this way wastes resources and may cause issues.  The only reason you would want to do it this way is if the function needs to change each time you open the chart, and even then there may be a better way.